# sed remove first two octets from ip

Tags: regex, bash, networking, sed

I have a file that contains a bunch of ip addresses. I would like for my sed command to remove the first two octets of these.
ex. `172.0.0.1` should be changed to `XXX.ZZZ.0.1`

What I have now remove the lasts octets and replace it with an x!

`sed -i 's/\(\([0-9]\{1,3\}\.\)\{3\}\)[0-9]\{1,3\}/\1XXX/g' "${file}"`

This is run in a bash scripts that takes the file containing the ip addresses as input param.

I haven't been able to figure out how to do this with sed yet so I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: Try [`sed -E 's/\b[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})\b/XXX.ZZZ.\1/g'`](https://ideone.com/OAcWL0)

Comment: Excellent, with a -i and the file with the ip's to be replaced as parameter this worked like a charm!

Comment: s/remove/redact/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you may use

```
sed -i.bak -E 's/\b([0-9]{1,3}\.){2}([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})\b/XXX.ZZZ.\2/g' "${file}"
```

The `-E`  (or `-r` on other OSes) enables the POSIX ERE syntax that allows using fewer escapes in the pattern (no need to escape grouping `(` and `)` symbols and the limiting/range quantifier `{n,m}`).

**Details**

- `\b` - word boundary
- `([0-9]{1,3}\.){2}` - two occurences of (Group 1) one to three digits and a dot
- `([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})` - (Group 2) one to three digits, a `.` and again 1 to 3 digits
- `\b` - word boundary

The whole match is replaced with Group 2 value (`\2`). The `-i.bak` will make the replacements in file, and an original copy with a .bak extension will be generated.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/OAcWL0).